# Deciphering UPS Rate Response

Tags: json, xml, ups

Hoping someone experienced with UPS can give me a hand deciphering the UPS Rates responses I am getting. Usually this is not an issue but I can't seem to make logical sense of the nesting going on. I am getting prices but no descriptions as to what the prices are? In the end I know I am looking at this all wrong. In short I am just trying to return a list of options and prices for an eCommerce website. The response is actually in JSON but I converted it to XML as XML is more readable to me. The main two things I am trying to figure out is 
1. where do the prices loop every time I think I see a loop in an element it breaks into something else!

2. How do I get/ find a description for the returned prices/ options?

Sorry for the mess but here is an example of a response:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <PropertyChanged null="true" />
   <ratedShipmentField>
      <element>
         <PropertyChanged null="true" />
         <baseServiceChargeField null="true" />
         <billableWeightCalculationMethodField null="true" />
         <billingWeightField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <unitOfMeasurementField>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <codeField>LBS</codeField>
               <descriptionField>Pounds</descriptionField>
            </unitOfMeasurementField>
            <weightField>10.0</weightField>
         </billingWeightField>
         <disclaimerField null="true" />
         <fRSShipmentDataField null="true" />
         <guaranteedDeliveryField null="true" />
         <itemizedChargesField null="true" />
         <negotiatedRateChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <itemizedChargesField null="true" />
            <taxChargesField null="true" />
            <totalChargeField>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <codeField null="true" />
               <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
               <descriptionField null="true" />
               <monetaryValueField>11.51</monetaryValueField>
               <subTypeField null="true" />
            </totalChargeField>
            <totalChargesWithTaxesField null="true" />
         </negotiatedRateChargesField>
         <rateChartField null="true" />
         <ratedPackageField>
            <element>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <accessorialField null="true" />
               <baseServiceChargeField null="true" />
               <billingWeightField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <unitOfMeasurementField>
                     <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                     <codeField>LBS</codeField>
                     <descriptionField>Pounds</descriptionField>
                  </unitOfMeasurementField>
                  <weightField>10.0</weightField>
               </billingWeightField>
               <itemizedChargesField null="true" />
               <negotiatedChargesField null="true" />
               <serviceOptionsChargesField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <codeField null="true" />
                  <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
                  <descriptionField null="true" />
                  <monetaryValueField>0.00</monetaryValueField>
                  <subTypeField null="true" />
               </serviceOptionsChargesField>
               <totalChargesField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <codeField null="true" />
                  <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
                  <descriptionField null="true" />
                  <monetaryValueField>11.63</monetaryValueField>
                  <subTypeField null="true" />
               </totalChargesField>
               <transportationChargesField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <codeField null="true" />
                  <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
                  <descriptionField null="true" />
                  <monetaryValueField>11.63</monetaryValueField>
                  <subTypeField null="true" />
               </transportationChargesField>
               <weightField>10.0</weightField>
            </element>
         </ratedPackageField>
         <ratedShipmentAlertField>
            <element>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <codeField>110971</codeField>
               <descriptionField>Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference rates</descriptionField>
            </element>
         </ratedShipmentAlertField>
         <ratingMethodField null="true" />
         <serviceField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField>03</codeField>
            <descriptionField />
         </serviceField>
         <serviceOptionsChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField null="true" />
            <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
            <descriptionField null="true" />
            <monetaryValueField>0.00</monetaryValueField>
            <subTypeField null="true" />
         </serviceOptionsChargesField>
         <taxChargesField null="true" />
         <timeInTransitField null="true" />
         <totalChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField null="true" />
            <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
            <descriptionField null="true" />
            <monetaryValueField>11.63</monetaryValueField>
            <subTypeField null="true" />
         </totalChargesField>
         <totalChargesWithTaxesField null="true" />
         <transportationChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField null="true" />
            <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
            <descriptionField null="true" />
            <monetaryValueField>11.63</monetaryValueField>
            <subTypeField null="true" />
         </transportationChargesField>
      </element>
      <element>
         <PropertyChanged null="true" />
         <baseServiceChargeField null="true" />
         <billableWeightCalculationMethodField null="true" />
         <billingWeightField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <unitOfMeasurementField>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <codeField>LBS</codeField>
               <descriptionField>Pounds</descriptionField>
            </unitOfMeasurementField>
            <weightField>10.0</weightField>
         </billingWeightField>
         <disclaimerField null="true" />
         <fRSShipmentDataField null="true" />
         <guaranteedDeliveryField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <businessDaysInTransitField>3</businessDaysInTransitField>
            <deliveryByTimeField null="true" />
         </guaranteedDeliveryField>
         <itemizedChargesField null="true" />
         <negotiatedRateChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <itemizedChargesField null="true" />
            <taxChargesField null="true" />
            <totalChargeField>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <codeField null="true" />
               <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
               <descriptionField null="true" />
               <monetaryValueField>19.99</monetaryValueField>
               <subTypeField null="true" />
            </totalChargeField>
            <totalChargesWithTaxesField null="true" />
         </negotiatedRateChargesField>
         <rateChartField null="true" />
         <ratedPackageField>
            <element>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <accessorialField null="true" />
               <baseServiceChargeField null="true" />
               <billingWeightField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <unitOfMeasurementField>
                     <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                     <codeField>LBS</codeField>
                     <descriptionField>Pounds</descriptionField>
                  </unitOfMeasurementField>
                  <weightField>10.0</weightField>
               </billingWeightField>
               <itemizedChargesField null="true" />
               <negotiatedChargesField null="true" />
               <serviceOptionsChargesField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <codeField null="true" />
                  <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
                  <descriptionField null="true" />
                  <monetaryValueField>0.00</monetaryValueField>
                  <subTypeField null="true" />
               </serviceOptionsChargesField>
               <totalChargesField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <codeField null="true" />
                  <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
                  <descriptionField null="true" />
                  <monetaryValueField>20.19</monetaryValueField>
                  <subTypeField null="true" />
               </totalChargesField>
               <transportationChargesField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <codeField null="true" />
                  <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
                  <descriptionField null="true" />
                  <monetaryValueField>20.19</monetaryValueField>
                  <subTypeField null="true" />
               </transportationChargesField>
               <weightField>10.0</weightField>
            </element>
         </ratedPackageField>
         <ratedShipmentAlertField>
            <element>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <codeField>110971</codeField>
               <descriptionField>Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference rates</descriptionField>
            </element>
         </ratedShipmentAlertField>
         <ratingMethodField null="true" />
         <serviceField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField>12</codeField>
            <descriptionField />
         </serviceField>
         <serviceOptionsChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField null="true" />
            <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
            <descriptionField null="true" />
            <monetaryValueField>0.00</monetaryValueField>
            <subTypeField null="true" />
         </serviceOptionsChargesField>
         <taxChargesField null="true" />
         <timeInTransitField null="true" />
         <totalChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField null="true" />
            <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
            <descriptionField null="true" />
            <monetaryValueField>20.19</monetaryValueField>
            <subTypeField null="true" />
         </totalChargesField>
         <totalChargesWithTaxesField null="true" />
         <transportationChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField null="true" />
            <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
            <descriptionField null="true" />
            <monetaryValueField>20.19</monetaryValueField>
            <subTypeField null="true" />
         </transportationChargesField>
      </element>
      <element>
         <PropertyChanged null="true" />
         <baseServiceChargeField null="true" />
         <billableWeightCalculationMethodField null="true" />
         <billingWeightField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <unitOfMeasurementField>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <codeField>LBS</codeField>
               <descriptionField>Pounds</descriptionField>
            </unitOfMeasurementField>
            <weightField>10.0</weightField>
         </billingWeightField>
         <disclaimerField null="true" />
         <fRSShipmentDataField null="true" />
         <guaranteedDeliveryField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <businessDaysInTransitField>2</businessDaysInTransitField>
            <deliveryByTimeField>10:30 A.M.</deliveryByTimeField>
         </guaranteedDeliveryField>
         <itemizedChargesField null="true" />
         <negotiatedRateChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <itemizedChargesField null="true" />
            <taxChargesField null="true" />
            <totalChargeField>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <codeField null="true" />
               <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
               <descriptionField null="true" />
               <monetaryValueField>28.86</monetaryValueField>
               <subTypeField null="true" />
            </totalChargeField>
            <totalChargesWithTaxesField null="true" />
         </negotiatedRateChargesField>
         <rateChartField null="true" />
         <ratedPackageField>
            <element>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <accessorialField null="true" />
               <baseServiceChargeField null="true" />
               <billingWeightField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <unitOfMeasurementField>
                     <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                     <codeField>LBS</codeField>
                     <descriptionField>Pounds</descriptionField>
                  </unitOfMeasurementField>
                  <weightField>10.0</weightField>
               </billingWeightField>
               <itemizedChargesField null="true" />
               <negotiatedChargesField null="true" />
               <serviceOptionsChargesField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <codeField null="true" />
                  <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
                  <descriptionField null="true" />
                  <monetaryValueField>0.00</monetaryValueField>
                  <subTypeField null="true" />
               </serviceOptionsChargesField>
               <totalChargesField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <codeField null="true" />
                  <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
                  <descriptionField null="true" />
                  <monetaryValueField>29.15</monetaryValueField>
                  <subTypeField null="true" />
               </totalChargesField>
               <transportationChargesField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <codeField null="true" />
                  <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
                  <descriptionField null="true" />
                  <monetaryValueField>29.15</monetaryValueField>
                  <subTypeField null="true" />
               </transportationChargesField>
               <weightField>10.0</weightField>
            </element>
         </ratedPackageField>
         <ratedShipmentAlertField>
            <element>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <codeField>110971</codeField>
               <descriptionField>Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference rates</descriptionField>
            </element>
         </ratedShipmentAlertField>
         <ratingMethodField null="true" />
         <serviceField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField>59</codeField>
            <descriptionField />
         </serviceField>
         <serviceOptionsChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField null="true" />
            <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
            <descriptionField null="true" />
            <monetaryValueField>0.00</monetaryValueField>
            <subTypeField null="true" />
         </serviceOptionsChargesField>
         <taxChargesField null="true" />
         <timeInTransitField null="true" />
         <totalChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField null="true" />
            <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
            <descriptionField null="true" />
            <monetaryValueField>29.15</monetaryValueField>
            <subTypeField null="true" />
         </totalChargesField>
         <totalChargesWithTaxesField null="true" />
         <transportationChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField null="true" />
            <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
            <descriptionField null="true" />
            <monetaryValueField>29.15</monetaryValueField>
            <subTypeField null="true" />
         </transportationChargesField>
      </element>
      <element>
         <PropertyChanged null="true" />
         <baseServiceChargeField null="true" />
         <billableWeightCalculationMethodField null="true" />
         <billingWeightField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <unitOfMeasurementField>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <codeField>LBS</codeField>
               <descriptionField>Pounds</descriptionField>
            </unitOfMeasurementField>
            <weightField>10.0</weightField>
         </billingWeightField>
         <disclaimerField null="true" />
         <fRSShipmentDataField null="true" />
         <guaranteedDeliveryField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <businessDaysInTransitField>2</businessDaysInTransitField>
            <deliveryByTimeField null="true" />
         </guaranteedDeliveryField>
         <itemizedChargesField null="true" />
         <negotiatedRateChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <itemizedChargesField null="true" />
            <taxChargesField null="true" />
            <totalChargeField>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <codeField null="true" />
               <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
               <descriptionField null="true" />
               <monetaryValueField>25.97</monetaryValueField>
               <subTypeField null="true" />
            </totalChargeField>
            <totalChargesWithTaxesField null="true" />
         </negotiatedRateChargesField>
         <rateChartField null="true" />
         <ratedPackageField>
            <element>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <accessorialField null="true" />
               <baseServiceChargeField null="true" />
               <billingWeightField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <unitOfMeasurementField>
                     <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                     <codeField>LBS</codeField>
                     <descriptionField>Pounds</descriptionField>
                  </unitOfMeasurementField>
                  <weightField>10.0</weightField>
               </billingWeightField>
               <itemizedChargesField null="true" />
               <negotiatedChargesField null="true" />
               <serviceOptionsChargesField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <codeField null="true" />
                  <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
                  <descriptionField null="true" />
                  <monetaryValueField>0.00</monetaryValueField>
                  <subTypeField null="true" />
               </serviceOptionsChargesField>
               <totalChargesField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <codeField null="true" />
                  <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
                  <descriptionField null="true" />
                  <monetaryValueField>26.23</monetaryValueField>
                  <subTypeField null="true" />
               </totalChargesField>
               <transportationChargesField>
                  <PropertyChanged null="true" />
                  <codeField null="true" />
                  <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
                  <descriptionField null="true" />
                  <monetaryValueField>26.23</monetaryValueField>
                  <subTypeField null="true" />
               </transportationChargesField>
               <weightField>10.0</weightField>
            </element>
         </ratedPackageField>
         <ratedShipmentAlertField>
            <element>
               <PropertyChanged null="true" />
               <codeField>110971</codeField>
               <descriptionField>Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference rates</descriptionField>
            </element>
         </ratedShipmentAlertField>
         <ratingMethodField null="true" />
         <serviceField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField>02</codeField>
            <descriptionField />
         </serviceField>
         <serviceOptionsChargesField>
            <PropertyChanged null="true" />
            <codeField null="true" />
            <currencyCodeField>USD</currencyCodeField>
            <descriptionField null="true" />
            <monetaryValueField>0.00</monetaryValueField>
            <subTypeField null="true" />
        ...
</root>
```

Comment: Rather than trying to decipher that mess, try using a 3rd party library. Like shippo for example https://github.com/goshippo

Comment: @mxmissile I love it, thank you! I think it is a much better solution as I see it gives more carrier options like USPS. While I knew third parties existed doing it directly with UPS was free. However Shippo seems to offer really reasonable prices for the service so I think it is more than worth doing the switch.

Comment: @mxmissile please write it as an answer so I can award it.

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs: It's not an answer, because it does not directly answer your question about working with the XML you posted. It's a recommendation for an off-site service, which is inappropriate here. If it gets posted as an answer, it will most likely be heavily downvoted.

Comment: @KenWhite is right, It was more of just a suggestion, hence the comment